# Sort list of strings in natural fashion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following:

```
sorted( ("A","a","b","B","CC","c"), key=lambda x: x.lower() )
```

Which gives:

```
['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'CC']
```

How do I sort it like this:

```
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'CC']
```

where if there are two values the same, the lower form comes first - a before A.

I'm guessing I do something like this:

```
sorted( ("A","a","b","B","CC","c"), key=lambda x: (x.lower(),x) )
```

but this gives A before a:

```
['A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'c', 'CC']
```

How do I do the opposite?

**UPDATE**

To clarify things further, the following strings: ["A","a","aA","aa"] should be sorted as:

```
["a","A","aa","aA"]
```

So "aa" before "aA" and "aaA" before "aAa" etc.

So:

```
lst = ["A","aA","aa","aaa","aAa","aaA","b","B","CC","c"]
```

should sort to:

```
['A', 'aa', 'aA', 'aaa', 'aaA', 'aAa', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'CC']
```

Comment: Others already provide solutions, I want only to add that Python `sorted` is stable sort: if multiple records have same key (as `a` and `A` in your case), their original order is preserved.

Answer (score 9):

You could do:

```
lst = ["A","a","b","B","CC","c"]

result = sorted(lst, key= lambda x: (x.lower(), not x.islower()))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'CC']
```

**UPDATE**

Given the new you examples you could use the following key:

```
lst = ["A", "aA", "aa", "aaa", "aAa", "aaA", "b", "B", "CC", "c"]
result = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x.lower(), ''.join(str(c.isupper()) for c in x)))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['A', 'aa', 'aA', 'aaa', 'aaA', 'aAa', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'CC']
```

For the other example (`["A","a","aA","aa"]`) it gives:

```
['a', 'A', 'aa', 'aA']
```

Comment: Updated my question since it wasn't fully clear with regard to what I want to do.

Comment: @Baz Updated the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way:

```
sorted( lst, key=lambda x: (x.lower(), *map(str.isupper, x)) )
#['A', 'aa', 'aA', 'aaa', 'aaA', 'aAa', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'CC']
```

First sort by case insensitive letter. Then call `str.upper` on all the characters of each string as the second sort condition. This will rank lower case letters first for the same length strings.

**Python 2 Version**

The above syntax only works in python3, but you can equivalently do the following in python2:

```
sorted( lst, key=lambda x: ((x.lower(),) + tuple(map(str.isupper, x))) )
```

Comment: Updated my question since it wasn't fully clear with regard to what I want to do.

Comment: @Baz makes sense. It's a simple change- fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> sorted( ("A","a","b","B","CC","c"), key=lambda x: (x.lower() + str(x != x.lower()) ,x) )
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'CC']
```

It works by comparing the lowercase version of the letter to the actual letter. If there is a match on lower case then `str(x != x.lower()` will be `0`, otherwise `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works based on previous answers:

```
sorted(lst, key= lambda x: (x.lower(), [c.isupper() for c in x]))
```

and this also seems to work:

```
sorted(lst, key= lambda x: (x.lower(), x.swapcase()))
```